# Nested join query for 'posts' and 'postmeta' wordpress tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have some data in the `posts` table and in the postmeta i have some `meta_key` with different values, for example:

> `meta_key` = 'phone'
>   `meta_value` = 987654321
>
> `meta_key` = 'score'
>   `meta_value` = 40

It is obvious that for a phone number there can be several points recorded.
I want to get total points of a phone number with its relation to the posts.
That query seems very complicated !!!

What I've tried is similar to this one:

```
SELECT p.*, pm.* from wp_posts AS r    
LEFT JOIN wp_postsmeta AS pm    
ON pm.post_id = r.id    
WHERE (pm.meta_key = 'score')    
LEFT JOIN wp_postsmeta AS p     
ON p.post_id = r.id    
WHERE p.meta_key = 'phone'
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: Can you please describe your desired result as a table?

Comment: The result is that the query is empty! in fact, this query has syntax errors.

Comment: So what would you like to see? please describe what is your **fictional** result.

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `AND`

Comment: `@JonnieJS 2`: I want to get total points of a phone number with its relation to the posts

Comment: `@Strawberry`: it's not working

Comment: @MHF 'It's not working' is not a permitted response on SO.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT p.*, pms.meta_value as score, pmp.meta_value as phone
FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN
     wp_postsmeta pms    
     ON pms.post_id = p.id AND pms.meta_key = 'score' LEFT JOIN   
     wp_postsmeta pmp     
     ON pmp.post_id = p.id AND pmp.meta_key = 'phone' ;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases should make sense. `r` does not make sense for `wp_posts`, but `p` does.
- `p.*` is a very odd thing to select.  I assume you really want the posts table.
- You should give the values returned by the query reasonable names, such as `score` and `phone`.
- The `where` clauses are both misplaced and misused in your query.  Those conditions should be in the `on` clauses.

EDIT:

Your revised question seems to suggest:

```
SELECT pmp.meta_value as phone, SUM(pms.meta_value) as score, 
FROM wp_postsmeta pms LEFT JOIN 
     wp_postsmeta pmp     
     ON pmp.post_id = pms.post_id AND pmp.meta_key = 'phone' and pms.meta_key = 'score'
GROUP BY phone;
```

Comment: `@Gordon Linoff` thanks, but i want total points of each phone.

Comment: `@Gordon Linoff`: Last your edit has extra comma end of `SUM(pms.meta_value) as score**,**`, that has caused an error